# Make elements move across smoothly when changing position css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a number flip effect using the number-flip npm package as a basis. I wish to make it similar to Robinhood's stock ticker (when scrubbing across a stock chart).

[image]

I have been able to customise the base number-flip package so that leading zeros and commas are removed when not necessary. However when the number of digits increases, the rest of the digits simply jump over to the right in position. I would like them to be smoother when moving over.

The current way I do it is, any leading zeros/commas are simply hidden using the position property and then if they are required, they are made visible again. This hiding/unhiding causes all the visible numbers to jump across and make it unsmooth.

I have linked code sandbox below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-taussig-ymfn9?file=/src/index.js

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I failed to go into all details of your code. It's pretty vast. But in order to achieve smooth animation, I suggest you manipulate the width (0 for hidden, 10px for visible) of each digit wrapper, instead of controlling their positions. CSS positions are not animate-able. Also, please make sure to apply the CSS transition of "all .2s", not "opacity .2s" - which will enable smooth animations by width property.

Comment: @FilipVeličković Thank you very much! This worked like a charm.